# How to limit search scope to many different URLs [SHAREPOINT 2016]

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search, result-source, search-results-webpart

I'm an admin of a site collection. I need to create a search-driven site for 3 teams which store the documents and files on 2 different platforms - one of them is SharePoint (of course both are indexed by SHPoint Search and visible in SharePoint SERP).

I want to retrieve the content under many different URLS (maybe 100 links) selected by me (manually) and tell the Search Engine: hey, search for the items stored only under those URLs.

My question is: do I have to use for that Managed Property "Path" when creating a new result source and add as values all 100 links?! Imagine how loooooong the query will be!

Or is there another smart way to create a result source containing URLs selected by me? Of course I'm not using PowerShell and similar tools. I want to do everything by changing the query. Is that possible?

I'll be veeery grateful for help.

Ag.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, there's no smart ways to create a result source containing URLs selected by you. You have to manually add the urls in the query builder.

[image]

Comment: As far as I recall the query lenght limit is 2048 char so that approach will only work for a limitted number of sites :-(

Comment: Yes, you're right, but fortunately, I found another managed property to narrow the scope down. :) Thank you for all answers, Kasper!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to guide the implementation I would suggest creating a Content Type for your purpose. If the documents or Items are of that content Type then they can show up in your search. If they are not, they won't.

Answer (score 0):

One option that will work but it is kind of a hack could be to pre or postfix the title of the site with an id like '_globalsearch' and use that as a short term solution

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answers. Saying: "no, it's impossible" is also a valuable answer. ;) Now I'm sure I can't do some things. 
Summa Summarum, I narrow down the scope by using another managed property.
Thanks again!
Regards,
Aga